# The return type 'StreamBuilder<dynamic>' isn't a 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>',

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The return type 'StreamBuilder' isn't a 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>', as required by the closure's context.

I want to query a table and get the results after comparing them with another table, but when there are no results, it should return something empty, but it does not accept anything
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't post images of the code, post the code instead, so someone can copy it and reproduce it ;)
By the way, i'm not sure what exactly do you want to do it.
If you want to return something empty when there are no results, you maybe want something like this:

```
 
   late Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> _stream;
 
 _stream = //query that you are doing;
 
 StreamBuilder(
          stream: _stream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            if (snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Nothing!',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                ),
              );
            }
            return ListView.builder(

                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                String name = snapshot['Name'];
                  return Text(name);
                });
          },
```

But again, i'm not sure what you want to do it.

Let me know if it helped!